# NSFileWrapper, lazy loading and saving

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsfilewrapper

I have an NSDocument based application that uses filewrappers to save and load its data.
The document can have all kinds of resources, so I don't want to load everything into memory. I might be doing something fundamentally wrong, but as soon as I change one (inner) file and then save, I can't read any file that hasn't been loaded into memory.

I have separated the relevant code into a separate project to reproduce this behaviour, and I get the same results. The basic flow is this:

- I load an existing document from disk. The main fileWrapper is a directory filewrapper (I'll call that *main*) containing two other filewrappers (*sub1* and *sub2*). The two inner filewrappers are **not** loaded at this point.
- When the user wants to edit *sub1*, it is loaded from disk.
- The user saves the document
- If the user wants to edit the other file (*sub2*), it cannot load. The error that appears:

  ```
  -[NSFileWrapper regularFileContents] tried to read the file wrapper's contents lazily but an error occurred: The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist.
  ```

**Here is the relevant code in my project:**

This code might be easier to read in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/bob-codingdutchmen/6869871

```
#define FileName01 @"testfile1.txt"
#define FileName02 @"testfile2.txt"

/**
 *  Only called when initializing a NEW document
 */
-(id)initWithType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.myWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:nil];

        NSLog(@"Initializing new document...");

        NSString *testString1 = @"Lorem ipsum first sub file";
        NSString *testString2 = @"This is the second sub file with completely unrelated contents";

        NSFileWrapper *w1 = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:[testString1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSFileWrapper *w2 = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:[testString2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        w1.preferredFilename = FileName01;
        w2.preferredFilename = FileName02;

        [self.myWrapper addFileWrapper:w1];
        [self.myWrapper addFileWrapper:w2];

    }
    return self;
}

-(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {

    // This obviously wouldn't happen here normally, but it illustrates
    // how the contents of the first file would be replaced
    NSFileWrapper *w1 = [self.myWrapper.fileWrappers objectForKey:FileName01];
    [self.myWrapper removeFileWrapper:w1];

    NSFileWrapper *new1 = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:[@"New file contents" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    new1.preferredFilename = FileName01;

    [self.myWrapper addFileWrapper:new1];

    return self.myWrapper;
}

-(BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    self.myWrapper = fileWrapper;
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender {
    // Read from file1 and show result in field1
    NSFileWrapper *w1 = [[self.myWrapper fileWrappers] objectForKey:FileName01];
    NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:w1.regularFileContents encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.field1 setStringValue:string1];
}

- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender {
    // Read from file2 and show result in field2
    NSFileWrapper *w2 = [[self.myWrapper fileWrappers] objectForKey:FileName02];
    NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:w2.regularFileContents encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.field2 setStringValue:string2];
}
```

The bottom two methods are only for updating the UI so I can see what happens.

- To change the contents of a file, I remove the existing fileWrapper and add a new one. This is the only way I've found to change the contents of a file, and the way I've seen it done in other SO answers.
- When a document is loaded from disk, I keep the fileWrapper around so I can use it (called *myWrapper* in the code above)

The Apple docs say that NSFileWrapper supports lazy loading and incremental saving, so I'm assuming that my code has some fundamental flaw that I can't see.

Comment: Does your document support versioning?

Comment: I'm not sure, so I think not :) I haven't done anything to support it. Would it change anything? I'll look into that later

Comment: As I'm using an NSDocument setup, I was supporting versioning. I've tried turning it off, but the result is the same

Comment: Have you tried going on the official Apple developer forums? You'll get experienced people there IMAO.

Comment: @SevenBits What does IMAO stand for?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem -- curious to know if you ever figured out how to fix this.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? Starting with macOS High Sierra, my app now shows the same error. It worked fine before...

Comment: I have since moved on from Mac app development, never found a solution for this unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

An NSFileWrapper is essentially a wrapper around a unix file node. If the file is moved the wrapper stays valid.

The problem yo seem to have is that creating a new file wrapper during saving is a new folder. And the system deletes your previous wrapper including *sub2*.

To achieve what you want you need to change to incremental saving, i.e. Only saving changed parts in place. See "save in place" in NSDocument.

Answer (score 1):

In your `-fileWrapperOfType:error:` method, try building a new file wrapper that has new contents for the changed members and references the old file wrappers for the unchanged members.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation to addFileWrapper: you add a child (subdirectory) to it, means

directory/

1. addfileWrapper:fileName1
   directory/fileName1/
2. addfileWrapper:fileName2
   directory/fileName1/fileName2.
   That file doesn't exist.

You have to use
addRegularFileWithContents:preferredFilename:
instead.